# MS access to SQL Server migration issue

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

I have a sql query below

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(Sub string([Short Description],9,Len([Short Description])-8))) AS PolicyNumber from x table
```

its giving error as this

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
>
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Which dbms are you migrating to? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: You wrote `sub string` instead of `substring`...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Actual, am in migration project from ms access query to SQL, this is the ms access query - Trim(Mid([Short Description],9,Len([Short Description])-8)) AS PolicyNo, what will be the exact sql query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the first 8 characters in SQL Server, use `STUFF()`:

```
select stuff([Short Description], 1, 8, '') as PolicyNumber
```